# Alphabetically partitioning indexes of substrings in C++ issues

Tags: c++, substring, partitioning

for a while now I've been trying to get this code to work to partition (as if preparing for quicksort) the indexes of substring suffixes, and while it's close I'm not getting what I'm expecting. I was wondering if a fresh set of eyes may help.

```
int partition(const string &S, vector<int> &indices, int low, int high, int pivotIndex)
{
    int i = low;
    int j = high - 1;
    swap(indices[high], indices[pivotIndex]);
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (i < high && !lessThan(S, S[i], S[indices[high]]))
            i++;
        while (j >= low && lessThan(S, S[j], S[indices[high]]))
            j--;
        if (i < j)
        {
            int temp = indices[i];
            indices[i] = indices[j];
            indices[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    swap(indices[high], indices[i]);
    return i;
}
```

Indices is simply a vector of 0, 1, 2, ..., n of same size as string S.

And here's the program I wrote for lessThan just so you know what I'm working with:

```
bool lessThan(const string &S, int first, int second)
{

    int counter = (int)S.length() - ((first <= second) ? second : first);
    for (int i = 0; i <= counter; ++i)
    {
        if (S[first + i] != S[second + i])
        {
            if (S[first + i] < S[second + i])
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (first < second)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

lessThan seems to work just fine when I test it separately, so I don't think it's the issue, but maybe it is.

Whenever I test, with say the string "abracadabra", and setting the pivotIndex to 4, I expect to get "0 1 8 3 10 5 7 4 2 9 6" as my output but I instead get "0 1 8 3 7 5 4 10 2 9 6". Close, but not quite. Can anyone spot my mistake?

(P.S. I know I could probably use substr() or some other solution to do lessThan easier, but I'm trying to do it without allocating extra memory, my focus is on the partition function)

edit: I figured it out. Complete error on my side. Check below for answer

Comment: Regarding the `substr` issue, if your compiler is new enough to support [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) then use that instead of `std::string`. No copying or memory allocations needed. And a general tip: Always do the simple and maintainable solution first. If the performance is not up to your requirements benchmark and profile to find the top two or three bottlenecks and optimize those (with plenty of comments and documentation). Then do one bottleneck at a time until performance is within tolerances of your requirements.

Comment: Oh cool, thank you, I didn't really know that string_view was a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was an idiot, input to lessThan was supposed to be given two ints. I instead gave it two chars from S. Also swapped which lessThan call the ! was on. I think I was just up too late programming and blame this all on sleep deprivation.

Fixed Code:

```
int partition(const string &S, vector<int> &indices, int low, int high, int pivotIndex)
{
    int i = low;
    int j = high - 1;
    swap(indices[high], indices[pivotIndex]);
    while (i <= j)
    {                                   //This right here
        while (i < high && lessThan(S, indices[i], indices[high]))
            i++;
        while (j >= low && !lessThan(S, indices[j], indices[high]))
            j--;
        if (i < j)
        {
            swap(indices[i], indices[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    swap(indices[high], indices[i]);
    return i;
}
```